# xCode objective-C Accessing variables inside a class in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c, xcode

What I am trying to do is have **Schedule** class containing multiple **Class** classes. just like in real life, a schedule contains several classes(lectures) in it.

I created this Schedule.h and .m :

in Schedule.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "myClass.h"

@interface Schedule : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *containsClassArr;
@end
```

and **containsClassArr** contains myClass.h objects.

So when I enumerate and NSLog each item in **containsClassArr**:

```
for(myClass *myclass in containsClassArr){
    NSLog("This Schedule contains class: %@", myclass);
}
```

the NSLog I get is:

```
This Schedule contains class: <myClass: 0x7fb78b4ab660>
This Schedule contains class: <myClass: 0x7fb78b493370>
This Schedule contains class: <myClass: 0x7fb78b4a7350>
This Schedule contains class: <myClass: 0x7fb78b4ab4c0>
```

---

Now, inside myClass.h, I have a variable like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *classTime;
@end
```

How can I access **NSString *classTime**?

I know this is wrong, but in my head I am trying to do something like this:

```
Schedule *newSchedule = [[Schedule alloc]init];

//assuming containsClassArr in newSchedule contains myClass objects already.
NSLog(@"Classes for Monday are:");
NSLog(@"class time -> %@", newSchedule.containsClassArr.myClass.classTime);
```

get:

```
Classes for Monday are:
class time -> 9am
class time -> 10am
class time -> 3pm
class time -> 5pm
```

1) What would be the correct access method for this type of .. access?

2) Is this kind of structure okay? or is there other recommended way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to specify on what member of the array you want to access the class property

```
int index = 0;
NSString* classTime = [newSchedule.containsClassArr[index] classTime];
```

You can either use the `[]` syntax which would not require a cast or you cast the returned value from the array and use the `.` syntax.

```
NSString* classTime = ((myClass*)newSchedule.containsClassArr[index]).classTime;
```

In both cases you have to assure that your index is within the array bounds.

If you want to iterate over the array you can access the property just as easy

```
for (myClass* myclass in containsClassArr) {
    NSLog("This Schedule contains class: %@ withValue: %@", myclass, myclass.classTime);
}
```

Comment: simple myclass.classTime inside fast enumeration worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exposing a mutable array is very poor:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *containsClassArr;
```

As the containing (`Schedule`) instance probably wants to know when classes are added/removed and so you should only allow the `Schedule` class to change the class schedule (the word "class" is confusing to talk about in OO programming).

Next you need to use the correct data type and using a string to hold a time is not using the correct data type:

```
NSString *classTime;
```

However WRT to accessing this property, what you have is OK, except that you probably just want to expose an immutable array of the classes...

Answer (score 0):

You'd use  KVC see [here](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) and [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html):

Try this:

```
NSArray *classTimeArray = [containsClassArr valueForKeyPath:@"classTime"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the following as it will be safe for nullable values and contains the index to for debugging purposes

```
[self.containsClassArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                if (myclass.classTime) {
                      NSLog("This Schedule contains class: %@ withValue: %@ at Position %i", myclass, myclass.classTime , idx);
                } 
           else {
            NSLog("This Schedule contains error at index: %i" , idx);
                }
            }
        }];
```